# Json not consistent between alert statement and functions

Tags: javascript, json, variables

I have a function that returns json (networks_function.php builds up some arrays and encodes them as json):

```
var json;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post("network_function.php", function(data) {
        json = data;
        alert(json);
    });
});
```

I pass the json variable to a new function which doesn't interpret it correctly.  However, when I copy the text of the alert statement and hard-code that into the second function (and set it equal to the json variable), it works.  I'm sure this isn't an issue with variable scope.  Does anybody know why this could be?

Comment: never use alert to debug. use `console.log(data)` instead. if the console shows an object, it's good JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It thinks it's not JSON.  Just tell jQuery that it's JSON data:

```
var json;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post("network_function.php", function(data) {
        json = data;
        alert(json);
    }, "json");
});
```

The reason that copy and pasting it works is because a JSON string when pasted into a JS context is an object literal.  When you alert an actual object (which is what you want to be alerting), you will see "Object" and maybe a bit of debugging information depending on the browser.

Note that you could (and should) also send json headers in your PHP file

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

Comment: Still not working.  I included the "json" string at the end of the jQuery, but nothing changed.  I still copied it out of the alert function and it worked, so I'm still not sure what's wrong.

Comment: @user1114864 Sorry, just realized I put the json in the wrong place.  Have edited my answer now, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using php at the backend.
You might want to do this:

Backend:

```
$dataToSend = array("item1"=>"data1","item2"=>"data2");
echo json_encode($dataToSend);
```

You can then get the "data" in jQuery as a JSON Object.
If php returns it as a string
Just do:

```
json = JSON.parse(data);
```

Your php is mostly not returning json properly so the quotes around your string in your echo might be a problem. This gets tedious to use the right quotes in php when returning JSON so using a json_encode() for an array would be the simplest way.